# SharePoint 2013 Creating List instance from existing list Template issue

Tags: list, list-view, viewfields

why (in sharepoint 2013 empty project) when we add new list based on existing list template we have the Tabs Views and Fields greyed? what can we do to be able to manipulate them?

Any help will be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your list is based on a SharePoint list template you cannot have access to these tabs.

Although, you can create lists based on custom content types from visual studios and then you will have access to views and fields tabs

Hope this helps